# Maven works in Powershell but not Cmd Prompt

Tags: java, windows, maven, windows-8

I installed Maven 3 and Java 7 in my Windows 8 64-bit machine. I am able to get an output from Maven within Powershell, but not with the cmd prompt (either as a regular user or as an administrator).

The following is the output of "mvn -v" in powershell:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 07:51:28-0600)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

And this is the output of my %PATH% (echoed from CMD) **Updated to use backslash and not forward slash**:

```
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin; C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

I thought that my PATH variables might be incorrect, but I do not think this is the case as it works in Powershell. Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

**Update**
This is what is displayed whenever I run "mvn --version" on the command line:

```
C:\Users\Hector>mvn --version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And here is the output of invoking the same command but in the Maven folder:

```
C:\Users\Hector>"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\
bin\mvn" --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 07:51:
28-0600)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

I should also note that these variables were created in my System Environment and not the User Environment (several posts led me to place them here). Thoughts?

I feel as if maybe `%M2% = %M2_HOME%\bin` might be broken.

Comment: Have you restarted the command prompt since installing maven/java/changing the path? edit: There's a forward slash at the end of the path to Maven, have you tried changing that to a backslash?

Comment: To isolate a possible path issue, try executing the Maven command with its absolute path.

Comment: Could you please provide the output from CMD when you execute `mvn -v`?

Comment: @Walkerneo You could post that path slash thing as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**

Despite having Maven installed correctly having the Environment Variables %M2% and %M2_HOME% defined properly, there was an issue running maven from the command line.

**Solution:**

It turns out that the System Environment PATH had *spaces between semi-colons*.

**Original:**

```
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin; C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

**New:**

```
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

I would like to thank everyone who posted. All the suggestions were extremely helpful in figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

Your maven path looks wrong. You have:

```
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5/bin
```

but the last slash should be a backslash

```
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

Comment: I have attempted to do this, but the command line still does not execute "mvn --version". Please see my updated post for more details.

Comment: @ProfessorElm, Sorry, I don't know what else the problem could be. Please come back and post your solution if you figure it out.

Comment: I found out the solution! Please see the answer posted if you are interested.